# React - How to render value and component under the same condition

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm trying to render a value and a component under the same condition, however, I don't know how to approach it correctly. Do I need to create a condition for each element?

```
<div>
    {values.cost && values.price ? values.gain+"€"+ 
    (<Button aria-label="copy1"><MdIcons.MdContentCopy/></Button>) : ""}
</div>
```

This way outputs `5.00€[object Object]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add value before button:

```
 {1 === 1 
  ? (<>
      <p>Hello, {props.name + props.surname}!</p> 
      <button>1</button>
      </>)
  : 'no'}

<div>
    {values.cost && values.price 
    ? (<>
           <span>{values.gain + "€"}</span>
           <Button aria-label="copy1">
               <MdIcons.MdContentCopy/>
           </Button>
       </>) 
    : ""}
</div>
```

This is an example at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-component-props-example-gvtfuu?file=index.js)

Comment: thanks for your comment, this way you say, it throws a bunch of errors, so it is not the right approach I believe.

Comment: @Germán sorry, please, see my updated answer

Comment: you forgot to add brackets: {values.gain+"€"} with this, it works as expected, please update your answer, so I can check it solved.

Comment: @Germán thanks, I've updated my reply

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator with component as well, as soon as the condition will get fulfilled, the component will also get rendered.

```
{ condition ? <Component> : "" }
```